# Deploy a project in local machine in server

Tags: webserver, symfony-1.4, virtualhost

I'm using Fedora and I deploy Symfony projects in my local machine using virtual hosts. How can I deploy my projects in server to public which others can view it through their machines?

Thanx...

Answer (score 1):

You have several way to deploy you symfony project. I will avoid ftp, svn up on prod, etc .. So, here is 2 good ways.

**The built-in deploy task**

Symfony comes with a [built-in depoy task](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/22#chapter_22_deploying) that has been used when symfony 1.4 was released. I think it's less and less used now (because there is better tool).

> The simplest way to deploy your website is to use the built-in `project:deploy` task. It uses `SSH` and `rsync` to connect and transfer the files from one computer to another one.

**Using capifony, which use Capistrano**

> *[Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano)* is an open source tool for running scripts on multiple servers. It’s primary use is for easily deploying applications.
>
> *[capifony](http://capifony.org/)* is a deployment recipes collection that works with both symfony and Symfony2 applications.

This way is far better than the previous one because you can automate many script when deploying (like testing your code, start a fresh built lib, upgrade database, share config file). But the most important one (from my POV) is that you can easily rollback a bad deployement. It's damm easy.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check them.